# アプリのアンインストール後にFCM topicを確認するとMissingIIdTokenエラーが出る理由

Tags: php, google-apps-script, firebase

firebaseのfcmを利用しプッシュ通知を作成しているのですが、どのような原因でerrorが表示されているかわからなかったので質問させていただきます。

前提
https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server?hl=ja
上記のサイトを参考にアプリインストール時にfcm_tokenをtopicに登録し、
https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/info/_TOKEN?details=true
上記のAPIで実行した際にちゃんと結果が返ってくることを確認しております。

```
Code: 200
Reason: OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Body: {"applicationVersion":"**","gmiRegistrationId":"**","application":"**","scope":"*","authorizedEntity":"**","rel":{"topics":{"hoge":{"addDate":"2023-12-28"}},"appSigner":"**","platform":"**"}
```

発生している問題・エラーメッセージ
その後、アプリのアンインストールを実行し、もう一度topic確認のAPIを実行すると以下の表記になります。

```
Code: 404
Reason: Not Found
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Body: {"error":"MissingIIdToken"}
```

こちら一度アンインストールするとtopicの登録自体が解除されているということでしょうか？
topicを対象としてプッシュ通知を送った場合、こちらは対象外として判断されているのでしょうか？

token管理としてのベスト プラクティスには古いトークンをトピックから登録解除するとあるのですが、こちらが対象なのか教えていただければ幸いです。
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/manage-tokens?hl=ja#unsubscribe_stale_tokens_from_topics

---

I'm creating push notifications using Firebase's fcm, but I don't know what causes the error to be displayed, so I would like to ask a question.

https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server?hl=ja
Referring to the above site, register fcm_token in the topic when installing the app,
https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/info/TOKEN?details=true
We have confirmed that the results are returned correctly when executed using the above API.

```
Code: 200
Reason: OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Body: {"applicationVersion":"**","gmiRegistrationId":"**","application":"**","scope":"*","authorizedEntity":"**","rel":{"topics":{"hoge":{"addDate":"2023-12-28"}},"appSigner":"**","platform":"**"}
```

After that, if you uninstall the app and run the topic confirmation API again, you will see the following notation.

```
Code: 404
Reason: Not Found
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Body: {"error":"MissingIIdToken"}
```

Does this mean that once you uninstall it, the topic registration itself is cancelled?
If I send a push notification targeting a topic, will this be judged as not being targeted?

The best practice for token management is to unregister old tokens from topics, but I would appreciate it if you could let me know if this is the case.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/manage-tokens?hl=en#unsubscribe_stale_tokens_from_topics

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　このサイトは日本語で運営されています。日英併記は許容されていますが、タイトルは日本語で書いていただきますようお願いいたします。投稿は後からでも [edit] できます。参考: [英語で投稿してもいいですか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2314/19110)

Comment: 英語を使用してより広く回答を募りたい場合は、[Stack Overflow（英語版）](https://stackoverflow.com/)に投稿なさるのがよいと思います。
確かに、日英併記は許容されていますが、それは日本語が不得意な方が、あえて日本語で質問せざるを得ない場合のことです。
例えば日本語処理に関する質問です。
この質問はそうでは無いので、日本語だけを使って下さい。

Comment: 少し経ったので、とりあえず自分の方でタイトルを和訳しておきました。